# How Show AllItems.aspx View Default in Document Library

Tags: view, sharepoint-online

I accidentally changed the current view in Edit Web Part on SharePoint Classic Mode, from "Current View" Becomes "Summary View". But why View Default AllItems.aspx or All Documents disappears?

When I see All View, All Documents in View default does not show.

[image: picture here]

Answer (score 0):

The url of All Documents view should be /Forms/AllItems.aspx. Check if you could go to the AllItems.aspx with the url https://yoursite/libraryname/Forms/AllItems.aspx.

If it show error： 404 NOT FOUND. The view could be deleted. As a workaround, You could create a new view use the url AllItems.aspx.